# Symfony2 AppCache behaviour on HTTP Methods PUT and DELETE

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, http-caching

Perhaps and hopefully is somebody able to explain following behavior of a `Symfony2` application (v2.3):

As soon as we wrapped the app kernel in the Symfony `AppCache`, the forms using `HTTP` methods `DELETE` or `PUT` didn't work anymore. The forms using method `PUT` wont validate anymore and submitting forms using method `DELETE`, result in:

> 405 - Method not allowed.

I've replaced `PUT` and `DELETE` with `POST` but I really would like to know more about it. I'm can't find any related posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get things clear from here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#safe-methods

Regarding the method now allowed, Have you created the hidden field for that method?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We don't try to cache any PUT or DELETE methods, this is clearly not possible. The hidden fields seemed to be created correctly. Because the method of the form is PUT or DELETE after calling `code`  $form->handleRequest($request);. It fails after this process. I will set up a clean app and test it again and will have a look at it again with your input. Thanks in advance.